# Find Similar Topics ( duplicate nominates) in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

We have a websites which users can post Content to website and after moderation check Contents they published,*Title* and *Description* are the most important field that content, we want to prevent users to publish similar posts So we looking for implement a method to find similar post and  hint the moderation these content are very similar to some old posts and moderator check them carefully for duplication, I mean warn moderation them as Suspicious duplicates, we index all content in Elastic search and  my question about the optimum query we have to write.
This is part of code we tried but

```
    $nameDesc = $title->Title. ' ' . $item->Description;

    $query = [
        '_source' => ['name', 'description', 'price'],
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'fields' => ['title', 'description'],
                        'type' => 'cross_fields',
                        'query' => $nameDesc
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'not' => [
                        'ids' => ['values' => [$item->ID]]
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ];
    $dupeCandidates = $this->indexService->buildSearch('articles', $query)->setLimit(4)->get();
```

I suppose it's better instead of concat *Title* and *Description* and do cross_fields multi match, try two separate match query, or better solution.

**In concise We're looking for optimum query detect high similar content by Title and Description in Elasticsearch**.

**Update**

according to one of answer has been proposed  I tried following snippet but  there is no result ( I tried a title that exactly exists in indexed )

```
GET /_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "more_like_this":{
               "fields":[ "title", "description" ],
               "like": "EXAMPLE EXIST TILE",
               "min_term_freq":1,
               "max_query_terms":100,
               "min_doc_freq":0
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Ref @cs25 mentioned a good solution is using `more_like_this`

```
{
            "min_score": 5,
            "query":
                {"filtered": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": {
                                "more_like_this": {
                                    "fields": ["title","desc"],
                                    "like": {
                                        "doc": {
                                            "title": item["title"],
                                            "desc": item["desc"],
                                        },
                                    },
                                    "min_term_freq": 1,
                                    "max_query_terms": 100,
                                    "min_doc_freq": 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "not": {
                            "term": {
                                "id": item["id"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                }
        }
```

Ref : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-mlt-query.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MLT(more-like-this) Query of Elasticsearch. It works pretty fine to give similar based results. 
Check out this link for implementation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-mlt-query.html

Comment: can you provide it's query?

Comment: I saw that link, it seems fine , but I'm looking for a solution  do similarity in two field,  title with title and  description with description,

Answer (score 1):

`match` and `match_phrase` statements can be used in combination with each other by indexing your fields multiple times with different analyzers depending on what you are trying to accomplish. One way would be to index fields (title, description) as both `analyzed` and `not_analyzed`.

**Elasticsearch 2.x**

In Elasticsearch < 5.x, if you index fields as strings, they [default to being analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2). You should only need to specify the index as being `not_analyzed` when defining a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields) (this can be anything, the examples below specify `raw` as the multi-field used for `not_analyzed` fields).

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type":  "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type":  "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Elasticsearch 5.x**

In newer releases of Elasticsearch, defining a [field datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_field_datatypes) would determine whether or not a field or multi-field should be analyzed, for example `text (analyzed)` and `keyword (not_analyzed)`.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After defining mappings, go ahead and index some documents if you haven’t already

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_type", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "title" : "Test Title 1", "description": "Test Description 1" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_type", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "title" : "Test Title 2", "description": "Test Description 2" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "my_type", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "title" : "Test Title 3", "description": "Test Description 3" }
```

If your application needs to search content that is identical `OR` similar to user input and you’ve indexed your fields correctly, you can build the search document by using a `bool` query that specifies multiple `SHOULD` clauses using a `match` and `match_phrase` statement for each field the application needs to search on to determine whether or not a document exists.

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "Test Title"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "description": "Test Title"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title.raw": "Test Title"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description.raw": "Test Title"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above, using `Test`, `Title` and `Description` values separately should respond with results from fields indexed as `text (analyzed)`, and `Test Title 1` or `Test Description 1` values should respond with results from fields indexed as `keyword (not_analyzed)`. This was tested on Elasticsearch 5.5.

Comment: tnx for you attetion and spend time,  we have had indexed data in elastics , what is your idea about put  title matching in  must section and  put description matching in should section?

Comment: I tired this , not result even in exact duplication item.

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you using? Their search API has changed since version 2.x. See edits.

Comment: my elastic  version is `"number" : "2.3.5",`